# Moving from ui-Bootstrap to ng-Boostrap

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap-tab

I want to migrate from ui-bootstrap to ng-bootstrap as they both are really different.How do you migrate from ui-Bootstrap to ng-Bootstrap?
do you have some migration guide?